# Is there any way of transferring wireless internet from my pc to ps3?

Tags: pc, ps3

This question is really killing me, and I apologize in advance if I'm not explaining my problem correctly.

Here's the problem, the router for my dsl internet is about 5 rooms down in my dad's room. I manage to pick up wireless signal in my room, mainly in my pc. The ps3 does pick it up, however, most of the time I barely get any type of speed, causing me to lag in games.

Is there any way that I can connect my ps3 to my pc and have internet on my ps3? Since my pc can have much better speed connecting to my router, I'm trying to find a wired solution for my ps3. 5 rooms is a long distance, so a wire through the walls is out of question.

Comment: You could connect your PC directly to your PS3 via a cross-over ethernet cable using your PC as an access point. You will need to configure a second network connection on your PC.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy 2 home plugs. The first one gets plugged in to the wall by the router withe a ethanet cable in it and the second one goes in your room with a cable going from it to ur ps3. It sends the connections through the mains there for acting like you are wired to it. Also both the plugs have to be on the same . You also get the full Internet speed

I know its a late awnser but if you haven't fixed your problem then this will.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are wanting to do this wirelessly there are limited options.

You will need Windows 7 to do this.

Also a warning that I know these exist and have read things about it but have not tried doing this.

There is a program called [Connectifiy](http://www.connectify.me/) which uses the built in software in Windows 7 to turn your computer into a wireless access point buy using another network connection including a wireless network you are connected to.

There is also a program called [Virtual Router](https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) that is similar/does the same thing and is open source at Codeplex.

If you are feeling adventurous you can also try doing this yourself and not using a program. I will point you [to this google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=Virtual%20Wifi%20windows%207) which come up with a few ways to do this yourself.

Both programs listed use something called Virtual wifi which is built into Windows 7. This lets you split one wireless card/connection into multiple. I have not seen anything for being able to do this for Windows Vista or XP.

Once the network is in place you can connect to it with your PS3 just like any other wifi network. Just make sure to turn it off when not using it. Hope this helps or pushes you in the right direction.

Comment: great advice ty. i have used connectify , but the speed is dead low. is there a way where i can connect my ps3 to my pc, with a wire and receive internet? thanks again

Comment: @Moe Yes similar to what was commented by James to your question. There are two ways. The easiest in my opinion is to bridge the two connections for instructions here is the microsoft article on how to do it [Network Bridge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-network-bridge). The other is through using Internet Connection Sharing in the properties of your wireless NIC but going this route there are sometimes other manual steps to perform on your PS3. Going either route you can sometimes use a regular ethernet cable instead of needing a crossover ethernet cable but it varies.

Answer (score -2):

You can also install burial router on your PC, then connect your PS3 through the virtual router. It works like magic.